# Eclipse Git : auto-synchronising 2 branches

Tags: eclipse, git, branch

I am working on a project with some mates.

Yesterday I cloned the project with the intention to add a functionality.
I have 2 local branches that are develop (the main branch) and pageContent (my feature branch).

The problem I am currently encountering is when I edit something on my feature branch, it automatically edits it on my developp branch too (I did not commit anything).

I checked out on my developp branch to delete the edition and when I checked out on my feature branch, the edition was deleted too ...

The branches seem to be auto-synchronised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I checked out on my develop branch to delete the edition and when I checked out on my feature branch, the edition was deleted too ...

## ***This is how git works***.

---

In the following diagram you can see the ***`3 states`***.
Git has three main states that your files can reside in.

[image]

---

They are all shared between your branches. but when you checkout branch you change the [***`HEAD`***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location/34519716#34519716) so you end up with the `staging area && working directory` shared between your repository even when you checkout branches.

---

Since you did not commit (i assume that what happened) when you switch branches you see the changes **following** you to your new branch.

If you don't want the changes to **follow** you you need to commit (or stash)  your work before switching to the branch.

#### `How to checkout different branch with clean working directory and stage area?`

If you wish to checkout clean branch without any "leftovers" in your working directory and staging are you can create a new `worktree` which will result in **shared view** of your repository  (all the content is shared) but with a **different** working directory and staging area.

---

#### From git v2.5

```
git worktree add <new_path>
```

Now do whatever you want in any of your branches. It will create 2 separate working folders separated from each other while pointing to the same repository.

Using wortree you don't have to do any `clear` or `reset` in order to remove all your staged and untracked content.

Here is demo of how to do it:

[image]

---